# Creating a linear datatable where data each pair of consecutive columns represents parent- child relation

Tags: c#

I have a datatable in C# with following structure.

```
id  name  parentid 
1    a      0
2    b      1
3    c      1
4    d      3
5    e      3
6    f      2
7    g      2
```

Now I want to create a datatable as follows

```
Parent child1 child2 child3 ....
a       b      f
a       b      g
a       c      d
a       c      e
```

Any Suggestions ??

Comment: Explain, i don't understand Your question

Comment: Sorry,Editing made :)

Comment: Would you have a row that has `"b"` is the first column as well or only "root" items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any Suggestions ?

In the end, there may be a clever Linq query that uses a recursive function, but think about how you would solve this logically and write that out in code:

1. Find all of the "root" items (items that don't have a valid parent)

   ```
   var roots = dt.Where(r => dr["parentid"] == 0);
   ```
2. for each root item, find all of the items that have that items ID as its parent

   ```
   foreach(var root in roots)
       var children = dt.Where(r => dr["parentid"] == root);
   ```
3. for each child, find the items that are children of it, etc.

2 and 3 can end up being a simple 3-4 line recursive function call - look up how recursive functions work and I'm sure you'll figure it out.  If not, post back when you're stuck.

Comment: Or for each item that doesn't have any children, write the list of parent, grandparent etc... (reverse the column order, if necessary)

Comment: Thanks for quick response @D Stanley